# Jquery Tools Slideshow Plugin : disable action onclick in <div class="images"> for use external link

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm new to jquery and i got a problem to use Jquery Tools Slideshow Plugin.
Could someone help me please.

For my case i have many link in a html block called (image like the example bellow)

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.htm

i would like to disable function onclick that passe my div to the next one. Because in my div i have many external links and i would like to allow the user to click on my links.

Finally, could someone tell me how to do that please.

Thanks in advanced.

Patrick

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

    // start from the beginning after the last tab
    rotate: true

// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div").unbind("click");
```

Or if you only want it for the ones containing links:

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div").has("a").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.slideshow({clickable:false});
```

You can pass it into slideshow as a param.

Answer (score 0):

I had to combine both answers above to get things to work.